# Using Doctrine ORM how to get a table to store record from its own table?

Tags: php, zend-framework, orm, doctrine

I'd like to store a a record from this table in the "parent" field. THe error produced is as follows

> Column name 'id' referenced for relation from MODL119\Entity\Role to MODL119\Entity\Role does not exist

And the PHP Entity class that produced the error

```
<?php
namespace MODL119\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/** @ORM\Entity @ORM\Table(name="role")
 */
class Role
{
    /** @ORM\Id
     *  @ORM\Column(name="role_id", type="bigint")
     *  @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $roleId;

    /** @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MODL119\Entity\Role")
     *  @ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="role_id")
     */
    protected $parent;



    public function setParent(Role $parent)
    {
        $this->parent = $parent;
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return $this->parent;
    }

    public function setRoleId($roleId)
    {
        $this->roleId = $roleId;
    }

    public function getRoleId()
    {
        return $this->roleId;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that you want to save a a record with a relationship to another record in the same table? If so, for this you an set up a self-referencing association mapping.

Comment: Yeah, it seems the name="field" actually creates this field in the table and the actually php variable stores the reference. Its weird to learn for Doctrine beginner. Thnx

Comment: Yeah, the parent will become a foreign key reference in the table. Is the relationship one-to-one, one-to-many or many-to-many? I see a couple of things with the above code but the answer depends on your desired relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property `Role::$parent` needs to be represented in the underlying table as a foreign key reference, so you need to amend your annotation and change the `JoinColumn.name` as follows:

```
/** 
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="MODL119\Entity\Role")
 *  @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="role_id")
 */
protected $parent;
```

This establishes a [one-to-one self-referencing association](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-self-referencing) in your entity, and creates a `parent_id` column in the underlying table.

See also:

- [one-to-many self-referencing association](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-self-referencing)
- [many-to-many self-referencing association](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-self-referencing)

Hope this helps :)